# Name for Monospace vs Proportional fonts?

Tags: font

If one wants to classify all fonts as either monospace (fixed-width) or proportional (variable-width), then how should this property of a font be called?

Comment: Is "width" not appropriate?

Comment: @Brendon: Generally, "width" is a horizontal measurement of something. A font has a stable height, also called the size of the font, but widths of individual characters vary in  proportional fonts -- so "width" of a font is a misnomer. "Widthness" may be appropriate, but that doesn't sound like a real word...

Comment: The names for Monospace vs Proportional are 'Monospace' and 'Proportional'

Comment: [The specification for OpenType uses a flag called "proportion"](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/os2.htm#pan), which maps to "a monospace / proportional flag".

Comment: @KitGrose: thanks Kit, this is the actual answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Everything that I've ever seen which deals with fonts assumes that they are proportional width fonts unless they are called "monospace" fonts, and without resorting to technical terms that only font creators are likely to know, there isn't a common term for that property.

So for the sake of clarity I would call them "monospace" and "non-monospace" fonts in the same spirit of "serif" and "sans-serif" where "sans-serif" literally means "without serif".

If you need to list the property in a table or something similar, I would **call the property "monospace"** and label it as true/false, yes/no, or ticked/unticked whichever best matches the style of the rest of the table.

Comment: The common terms are, indeed, monospace and proportional.

Answer (score -1):

EDITED - Correcting myself, I had suggested that property could be letter-spacing or Kerning but its wrong. Letter-Spacing and Kerning represent spacing between font-characters and not width of characters which is being asked here.

Comment: -1 Letterspacing is the space BETWEEN letters. Monospace and Proportional refers to the widths of each glyph (or, more accurately, the bounding box of each individual glyph)